# Why special character "$-_.+!*'()," in URL encoding are special?

Tags: url, url-encoding, rfc1738

[RFC1738 SEC 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-2.2!) says that:

> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
> reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
> unencoded within a URL.

After some searching, I summarized that there are three types of characters that should be encoded:

- Unsafe characters:  '#', ' ', '"', '%', '<', '>', '{', '}', "|", '', '^', '~', '[', ']', '`'.
- Reserved characters: ';', '/', '?', ':', '@', '=', '&'.
- Special characters: "$-_.+!*'(),"

I know why and when unsafe characters and reserved characters should be encoded. RFC1738 states that special characters can be used uncoded, but I found that `urllib2.quote` also encode these special characters to `"%24-_.%2B%21%2A%27%28%29%2C%7E"`. So, I am a little confused about
why special characters are encoded if they can be used unencoded within a URL and why they are special.

Comment: Side note: You probably want to use [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) (which is [the URI standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/std66)) instead of RFC 1738.